# Analytical solution to marginal likelihood/normalizing constant

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo

I have a sample with data and I would like to compare the result I get from Monte Carlo integration and by analytically computing the marginal likelihood. Now I know that in many cases this is a challenging computation, but in this case apparently it is possible. I have the code for doing it, but I don't understand how it is done, and the code doesn't make me wiser.

So, let  $Y \sim N(\theta,1)$ and the prior on $\theta \sim N(0,1)$.

How would I analytically compute the  marginal likelihood $p(y)$

$$p(y) = \int p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)\, d\theta$$

Comment: Well, one way would be to compute it directly. Standard trick is to separate all factors with $\theta$ and complete them to a proper density so that the integral will be equal to $1$. If I remember correctly in your setup it will be $Y \sim N(0, 1 + 1)$

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad: (+1) you do remember correctly!